# Proving that $\sum_nX_n<+\infty$ a.s. where $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ a sequence of independent r.v.'s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

As in the titel we want to proof that $\sum_nX_n<+\infty$ a.s. where $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ a sequence of independent r.v.'s all on the same probability space $(E,\mathcal{E},P)$. We aslo know $P(X_n=\frac{1}{n})=P(X_n=-\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{2}$.
It is also noted that $E[|Z|]\leq E[Z^2]^\frac{1}{2}$ might be usefull.

I guess we have to use Borell Cantelli here but I don't see how?

Comment: Use the [Kolmogorov three series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem)

Comment: John is right - even two series will be enough in your case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_two-series_theorem