# Showing that random variable is finite almost surely.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am given the following. Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent random variables on the probability space $(E,F,P)$. Such that, for all n , we have
$$P(X_n=1/n)=P(X_n=−1/n)=1/2$$
How can I show that for $Y= \sum_{n\geq 1} X_n$ we have $|Y| < \infty$ a.s.? 
I cannot get it to work. Thanks :)

Comment: It is not directly *almost sure* convergence, but having $\text{Var}(Y)= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is encouraging

Comment: How would you compute the variance of Y?

Comment: It is the third time in few days that this question is asked https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575153/showing-that-y-sum-n-geq1x-n-converges-with-borel-cantelli-lemmas?noredirect=1#comment7352562_3575153 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573812/proving-that-sum-nx-n-infty-a-s-where-x-n-n-geq-1-a-sequence-of-inde

Comment: @SiemvanBenthem Since everything has zero expectation, $\text{Var}(Y)=\sum \text{Var}(X_n) = \sum \mathbb E[X_n^2] = \sum \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: Why to reproduce for the n-th time what has been said in the above links ? Bibliography is key not only in research. Even the MSE robot links this question to the two mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Kolmogorov 3 series theorem seems good here.